# triggering a function (JavaScript, jQuery), it should be simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, web

I have two functions. Notice the difference of first line in both functions defining when to trigger and execute. Both function are similiar, function#1 shows section which is not visible by default. Function#2 does pretty much same just in nicer way, it slides down and has nice animation. 

Function #1:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Function #2:

```
$('.toggleMUSIC').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.next().hasClass('showsection')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('showsection');
        $this.next().slideUp(200);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('showsection');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(200);
        $this.next().toggleClass('showsection');
        $this.next().slideToggle(200);
    }
});
```

Problem is, that function #2 trigers only button with class "toggleMUSIC", this gives me limit only to individual button with that class. Now I want to add more buttons with same behavior and unfortunately same class, that causes mess for the function and it doesnt work correctly because it has more than one element with class "toggleMUSIC".

Function #1 shows how I want it to be - triggeret by ID. I mark the ID of related div (this div will be hidden or shown) to the button element by this command to html code `<a  class="helper_button" onclick="toggle_visibility('helper1');">` . I am not sure if I use right terminology and if I have provided enough resources for my issue, if needed let me know.

Honestly, unbelievably I wrote these function by a miracle, trying and trying until it worked but it was long long time ago and unfortunately I did not understand that fully.

Attaching also HTML of both function for better better image.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no clue what you are actually trying to ask here. Since your second function seems to select everything based on the “this” context, it is unclear what exactly is causing you problems here when you try and apply this to multiple elements. // Code relevant to your question belongs directly into your question in text form, not just as images. Please create a proper [mcve] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: CBroke, how would you change 1st line of function #2 so it is very similar as 1st line from function #1? I tried this and ofc adjusted HTML but did not work. "(function toggle_visibility('id') { ..... than the rest of the lines unchanged" but no success.

Comment: _“how would you change 1st line of function #2 so it is very similar as 1st line from function #1?”_ - this still doesn’t make sense. The first line of #1 is `var e = document.getElementById(id);`, the first line of #2 is `e.preventDefault();` - which have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other. (Are you maybe simply confused by the fact that the variable name `e` is used in both cases …?)

Comment: aha, I see, I use worng words I guess. I see first line of function#1 this: "function toggle_visibility(id) {" and 1st line of function #2 this "$('.toggleMUSIC').click(function(e) {" . I think there is something common in these two. I need to fix that line of function #2. It should be something like line from function#1, so it listens to element ID and not element with class.

Comment: Both are fundamentally different already in that the first one needs to be called from somewhere, whereas the second one binds a click handler function to all elements that `$('.toggleMUSIC')` selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to trigger by ID and preserve the 'ease' of function 1, perhaps you want to wrap your function 2 into an actual, callable function:

```
var function = toggleMusic(id) {
        if ($('#' + id).hasClass('showsection')) {
            $('#' + id).next().removeClass('showsection');
            $('#' + id).next().slideUp(200);
        } else {
            $('#' + id).parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('showsection');
            $('#' + id).parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(200);
            $('#' + id).next().toggleClass('showsection');
            $('#' + id).next().slideToggle(200);
        }
}
```

You can then once more use the `onclick` event e.g. `onclick="toggleMusic('helper1');"`
You can replace the `$('#' + id)` in the above function by a variable for better readability.

The key take-away here is to realize the `$('.toggleMUSIC').click(function(e)` automatically adds a 'click-listener' to all elements with class `toggleMUSIC`. Since you don't want this, it's simply a matter of not adding this functionality.

Comment: Perfect, it starts to make sense, I will give it a try when Ill be home today. I need to study more about listeners. I have no intention to understand Javascript fully thats after few trys and fails I turn to stack-overflow, this is for page for my own use only. Thanks for clue @Roel Strolenberg